# Using Vault to encrypt remote Terraform state stored in Consul

Tags: terraform, devops, consul, hashicorp-vault

As of today, managing secrets such as cloud provider access keys and ids is an open problem in the Terraform project (see [github issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/516) ). Whenever, we run `terraform plan` or `terraform apply`, these secrets are stored in plain text in the terraform state file. There are numerous third party redaction and encryption scripts such as terrahelp.

My question: Consul is a native backend for storing remote terraform state. **Is it possible to use Vault to encrypt state files stored in Consul?** I have tried searching through the Terraform backend documentation, but was not able to find any configuration flags that would allow Consul to use Vault to encrypt the state file.

Comment: Not an answer because I don't have enough experience with Vault but could you use the transit backend for Vault to transparently encrypt it into Consul via Vault? Sounds odd because Vault is using Consul as a state store anyway but might work I guess?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR The idea is nice, but the problem is that there is no official way to hook into the read/store procedure - so incorporating vault's transit backend is more difficult. You could store the statefile locally, then encrypt it with vault and push the encrypted file to a remote backend. But for that you would need to use a custom wrapper around terraform. Terraform itself does not support such an approach (yet)

Comment: Ah, was thinking maybe you could change the consul host to just point to the vault cluster and the path to the transit backend but I guess you still need to provide a vault token somehow. Might be worth raising an issue at https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/ (the backends are still part of the main repo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As much as I would like that feature, sadly I don't think that this is possible at the moment. If you want your whole statefile encrypted, then you would need to choose another backend that supports this out of the box, like s3 with bucket encryption enabled.

It would also be nice if there is an official way to hook into the statefile read/store procedure to incorporate vault encryption (or any other custom requirements) by yourself, but afaik this is also not possible.

Small site note: `terraform plan` does not write anything to the statefile. It is a read-only operation, as otherwise it couldn't be considered safe to use.